# Does native English speaker find homograph hard to learn?

Tags: word-meaning, vocabulary, teaching

Through my own experience and my observation I find one big obstacle for learning new words in English is **homograph**.

For example, "turn right" and "you are right", "turn left" and "I have left there", "apple watch" and "watch TV", "river bank" and "bank account", "rose garden" and "rise/rose" (just to name a few), I have friends who teach English in primary school and high school in Beijing and they tell me that their students often feel confused that why these totally different meanings words spell the same. So they have a hard time to remember them.

Or why can a single word have so many different meanings, e.g. the letter "a" in longman dictionary https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/a have 16 items!

Of course Chinese also have homograph and homophone but to us the different meanings are closely related and we won't feel confused like when we learn homograph in English. I understand context is the key and sometimes when it comes to language rules, there is no why, just remember them. But still it is hard for us.

Does native English speaker find homograph hard to learn? If not how do you guys learn them **when you are kids**? I am asking this question for my teacher friends, to help them better teach their students (students of 1st grade of junior high school are normally 13 years old) especially when theirs students don't have many chances to talk to native speakers.

Comment: It would be useful to have some examples from your teacher friends because turn left and I have left there are not the same order of things. turn left versus leave, left, left.

Answer (score 4):

There are two things,  one is true homographs, like "bank" and "bank".  These are two completely different words that just happen to have the same spelling.  Then there are different senses of the same word.  The word "a" is a bad example, as it is really part of the grammar, and not meaning.

But, for example, "bright" has 7 main senses in Longman, plus another eight special uses in idioms.  But these meanings are all related. A native speaker might begin with a partial understanding of one meaning, and slowly add further senses to their repertoire by hearing the word used in different contexts.

If a native learner knows one of the meanings, but doesn't know another, then they may be confused. But it is very hard to find a sentence that is actually hard to understand in context. Native speakers, of any language, learn the spoken language before the written, and tend not to completely learn a few words a day, but incrementally build their knowledge of hundreds of words each day.

How long do you practice English for?  Five hours a week? Ten?  And how do you do it? Are you taking a class, or are you using a book.

Suppose you studied for more than 70 hours a week, with a team of native speaker tutors who were always with you, including a dedicated tutor who spends nearly all her time just talking with you.  And you know that if you want to communicate anything you need to use English, you need to use.  I'm sure, under those conditions, you would learn homographs quickly!

You ask "How do you guys learn them while you are kids"  - The same way that you learnt the different senses of Chinese words, or the different Chinese words that sound the same (but may have different written forms - because when you learnt these words, you couldn't read)  You pick them up from the linguistic environment provided by your family and friends.  I don't remember learning that "bank" could mean a "Money shop" and "side of a river" Nobody ever *taught* me these words.  Somehow I worked out the meanings from the use of the words in context. The same way that you learned "jìyì" could mean both "remember" and "skill" and "art".

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. I mainly ask this question for my teacher friends to help them better teach their students for that.

Comment: As I've suggested in the last paragraph,  "learning like you learned your native language" isn't really practical, because you'd need to be a baby with a mum.  Nobody has the time to learn like that!

Comment: I updated my question. Like you said "learning like you learned your native language isn't really practical", hence my question.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I have to say "jìyì" is not homograph (but homophone ) because the written words are totally different. But I got your idea.

Comment: The words meaning "skill" and "art" are homographs, or rather they are different senses of the same word.  But you can have learned these words long before you learned to write them.

Answer (score 2):

> Does native English speaker find homograph hard to learn? If not how do you guys learn them **when you are kids**?

I would like to talk about this part a little bit.  Kids don't have a problem learning this kind of thing, *because they are kids.*  Children's brains pick up languages very quickly: in fact, you could almost say that languages are designed for how children learn, because if a language was *not* easy for children to learn, it would change into something they could learn!  By the time a child is seven, they speak their native language (mostly) fluently, even if they have never had any formal training in it.

Adults are not like that: our brains are less flexible, and we have trouble learning a language simply by hearing it, so we try to learn by memorizing things, but this is difficult for the reasons that you mention.  I don't speak Chinese, but when you say "Of course Chinese also have homograph and homophone but to us the different meanings are closely related and we won't feel confused like when we learn homograph in English", I think "That's because you learned Chinese as a child!  I bet foreigners learning Chinese find homophones and homographs in Chinese difficult too!"

The best advice I can give is to always think of words *in context*.  For example, *rose* can mean "a flower" or "got up", but context will always tell you which one is intended.  In the real world, outside a classroom, no one is ever going to tell you "Give me all five definitions of the word *rose*!"

Answer (score 1):

> Of course Chinese also have homograph and homophone but to us the different meanings are closely related and we won't feel confused like when we learn homograph in English.

But all of the homographs you mention do have related meanings. Most people are right-handed, so the right hand seems "correct" to them. A wristwatch is used to keep track of shifts, and soldiers have shifts watching their sleeping comrades. A bank does business at tables, a table is like a shelf, and a riverbank is like a shelf of dirt. Yes, these meanings are several steps removed from each other, but they did evolve from the same meaning. Your Chinese homographs seem to have "closely related" meanings, while English homographs seem random, because you were brought up in Chinese culture. I'm sure there are Chinese homographs that you consider to have closely related meanings that seem random to English speakers. Also, your writing system isn't based on phonemes, so you don't have homophones giving rise to homographs as much as English does (although from what I've read, there is some influence from homophones, such as superstition from "four" sounding like "death").

> Does native English speaker find homograph hard to learn? If not how do you guys learn them when you are kids?

It does seem weird when one first comes across them, but it's just something one gets used to. We joke about it, making puns/riddles out of them. You might want to get a book of puns to help practice recognizing double meanings.

Comment: Make sense! But just out of curiosity, what about "turn left" and "I have left there" ?

Comment: _Left_ (verb) is the past tense of _to leave_.  It seems to be just a coincidence that we use the same word for the left hand. Incidentally., your entries from Longman are different _uses_ of the letter A rather than different meanings.